# In unity3d chess game I am unable to select or move pawn and rook at 7th location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pawn : ChessMan {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public override bool[,] PossibleMove(){
        bool[,] r = new bool[8, 8];

        ChessMan c, c2;
        int[] e = BoardManager.Instance.enPassant;

        //White move
        if (isWhite) {
            //diagonal left
            if (CurrentX != 0 && CurrentY != 7) {
                //Debug.Log (CurrentY);
                if (e [0] == CurrentX - 1 && e [1] == CurrentY + 1) 
                    r [(int)CurrentX - 1, CurrentY + 1] = true;

                c = BoardManager.Instance.Chessmans [(int)CurrentX - 1, CurrentY + 1];


                if (c != null && !c.isWhite) {
                    r [(int)CurrentX - 1, CurrentY + 1] = true;

                }

            }

            //diagonal right
            if (CurrentX != 8 && CurrentY != 7) {

                Debug.Log (CurrentX);
                if (e [0] == CurrentX + 1 && e [1] == CurrentY + 1) 
                    r [(int)CurrentX + 1, CurrentY + 1] = true;

                c = BoardManager.Instance.Chessmans [(int)CurrentX + 1, CurrentY + 1];
                if (c != null && !c.isWhite) {
                    r [(int)CurrentX + 1, CurrentY + 1] = true;
```

1. This is my code and I have a problem in condition below "diagonal right" comment that it is out of index in unity.
2. I have two more scripts boardmanager and chessman.

Thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `CurrentX` and `CurrentY` at the point the error occurs?

Comment: you are trying to access an element in an array that doesn't exist. Try checking the size of your arrays before accessing elements within them

Comment: 7 for x and 0 for y

Comment: using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public abstract class ChessMan : MonoBehaviour {

 public float CurrentX{ set; get;}
 public int CurrentY{ set; get;}
 public bool isWhite; 

 public void SetPosition(float x, int y){
 
  CurrentX = x;
  CurrentY = y;
 
 }
 public virtual bool[,] PossibleMove()
 {
  return new bool[8,8];
 }
}

Comment: ;
  DrawChessBoard ();
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   if (selectionX >= 0 && selectionY >= 0) {
    if (selectedChessman == null) 
    {
     //Debug.Log (selectionX);
     SelectChessman (selectionX, selectionY);
    } 
    else 
    {
     MoveChessman (selectionX, selectionY);
    }
   
   }
  
  }
   



 }

Comment: private void SelectChessman(int x, int y)
 {
  if (Chessmans [x, y] == null)
   return;
  if (Chessmans [x, y].isWhite != isWhiteTurn)
   return;

  bool hasOneMove = false;

  allowedMoves = Chessmans [x, y].PossibleMove ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)

Comment: private void SelectChessman(int x, int y)
 {
  if (Chessmans [x, y] == null)
   return;
  if (Chessmans [x, y].isWhite != isWhiteTurn)
   return;

  bool hasOneMove = false;

  allowedMoves = Chessmans [x, y].PossibleMove ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    if (allowedMoves [i, j])
     hasOneMove = true;

  if (!hasOneMove)
   return;


  selectedChessman = Chessmans [x, y];
  previousMat = selectedChessman.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material;
  selectedMat.mainTexture = previousMat.mainTexture;
  selectedChessman.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = selectedMat;
  BoardHighlight.Instance.HighlightAllowedMoves(allowedMoves);
 }
 private void MoveChessman(int x, int y){
  if (allowedMoves[x,y]) {

Comment: [edit] your question to make code readable.

Comment: did you finally solve this problem?

Comment: yes finally i did it

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show the whole code, it is going to be hard to spot the exact place where you have the mistake. But I will explain you what is the problem and how you can solve.

You define a Matrix (2 dimensional array) for your possible positions:

```
bool[,] r = new bool[8, 8];
```

This means the variables you will use as index to access these elements in the Matrix need to be in the following range:

**0 < CurrentX || CurrentY < 8**

Since you are increasing/decreasing this values in the same moment of accessing the the elements in the matrix, you will need to add a condition before. For example, for this case:

```
r [(int)CurrentX - 1, CurrentY + 1] = true;
```

You should write:

```
if(CurrentX > 0 && CurrentY < 7){
 r [(int)CurrentX - 1, CurrentY + 1] = true;
}
```

And do the same everytime you are going to access the Matrix `r`